# FFMPEG - Can't add watermark in JS file

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

Here's the part of my file which's about the FFMPEG string.

```
    if (transcoderType === 'ffmpeg') {
            // https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment
            var tsOutputFormat = 'stream%05d.ts';
            var args = [
                    '-i', file, '-sn',
                    '-async', '1', '-acodec', 'libmp3lame', '-b:a', audioBitrate + 'k', '-ar', '44100', '-ac', '2',
                    '-vf', 'scale=min(' + targetWidth + '\\, iw):-1', '-b:v', videoBitrate + 'k', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-profile:v', 'baseline', '-preset:v' ,'superfast',
                    '-x264opts', 'level=3.0',
                    '-threads', '0', '-flags', '-global_header', '-map', '0',
                    // '-map', '0:v:0', '-map', '0:a:1'
                    '-f', 'segment',
                    '-segment_list', playlistFileName, '-segment_format', 'mpegts', '-segment_list_flags', 'live', tsOutputFormat
                    //'-segment_time', '10', '-force_key_frames', 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)',
                    //'-f', 'hls', '-hls_time', '10', '-hls_list_size', '0', '-hls_allow_cache', '0', '-hls_segment_filename', tsOutputFormat, playlistFileName
```

I added this line to add watermark after '-i', file, '-sn',

```
-i', '/home/logo.png', '-filter_complex', "overlay=10:102",
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i file -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale[bg];[bg][1]overlay=10:102[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? … output
```

- Don't use both `-vf` and `-filter_complex`. Combine them into one `-filter_complex`.
- Remove `-map 0` and instead `-map` the output from the `-filter_complex`.